# Mysql extract alphabetical characters only

Tags: mysql, character, extract, alphabetical

I have a column which contains a mixture of letters and numbers. I need to get the first set of alphabetical characters from the column. As soon as an integer is encountered I don't want any more.. for example:

Take 5 rows:

- S123J90
- SF91K88
- JK12K99
- X129PL9
- ABCD123

I need the following data from these 5 rows

- S
- SF
- JK
- X
- ABCD

I have found a lot of talk about nested REPLACE queries but I'm sure there is a better option out there?

Note: All rows start with at least one alphabetical character

---

Update: I used a modification of this function http://www.rummandba.com/2011/02/mysql-function-to-remove-non.html as follows

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS remove_non_alpha_char_f //
CREATE FUNCTION remove_non_alpha_char_f (prm_strInput varchar(255))
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE v_char VARCHAR(1);
  DECLARE v_parseStr VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ' ';

WHILE (i <= LENGTH(prm_strInput) )  DO 

  SET v_char = SUBSTR(prm_strInput,i,1);
  IF v_char REGEXP  '^[A-Za-z ]+$' THEN  #alpha

        SET v_parseStr = CONCAT(v_parseStr,v_char);  
        SET i = i + 1;
  ELSE
    SET i=256;
  END IF;

END WHILE; 
RETURN trim(v_parseStr);
END
```

Note: I have re-coded the function for this answer so the syntax might be out.

Comment: do you need mysql to do this for you? It is fairly simple to do in any programming language outside of sql

Comment: I could do it in app code. I have 29M rows though.. If I could find a quick method in MySql I'm sure it would run a lot quicker.

Comment: ifound a link that you might find useful http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,137433,137433 Apparently its not simple to do, and it certainly is outside of my knowledge. My best bet would be creating a little script and another column (or table). This script goes through all the records once, and then stores the extracted characters in this new column. Later on, I would try to keep this column updated by changing the way this records are stored

Comment: Good call. A new col based on the old col filtered by a regex of alpha chars only might work well. I'll run it now on 100k rows and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a recursive function using SUBSTRING(), LENGTH() that checks each character to see if its alphabetical and then adds it to the result.

Have it quit once it reaches the end of the string or hits a number.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up modifying a version of this function (will post function in an answer): http://www.rummandba.com/2011/02/mysql-function-to-remove-non.html

Answer (score 0):

For each row, try the following:

```
$split = preg_split("/\d/", $your_str);
```

You want `$split[0]` from the array that is `$split`.

Note this is PHP - @Pablo is correct, do you really need MySQL to do this for you?